# create vbscript vbdataobject

Tags: vbscript, scripting

I am using a program which makes it possible to customize dialogues via vbscript. Now, the form has an attribute which seems to be a vbDataObject (VarType returns 13).

How can I read the content and create a new vbDataObject to assign it to the attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is exactly the answer, but it seems that vbDataObject's are indeed COM objects, but they just do not expose an IDispatch interface (so they're not true automation objects).  As such, VBScript just isn't capable of accessing their content, since it needs an IDispatch interface for it.  It just has an IUnknown interface which it doesn't know what to do with.

Passing them around should be possible, though, so if another true automation COM object can manipulate them for you (maybe there is such an object in the app designed to do this?), you could use that to make an object with the correct settings and pass that to the form.

Another option is to contact the authors of the app and ask them if they're willing to give this one object an IDispatch interface as well.  Since they presumably went the length to put IDispatch interfaces on most of their objects, this omission might just be an oversight on their part.

Comment: I found, there is no way to do so inside the program I am using, so I found another way around it by using different dialogues based on group roles where I have my specific vbDataObject preset.